# C++/WRL project unknown namespace Windows::Storage

Tags: c++, stream, wrl

In my Windows Store app I am using a C++ component in order to use a Sink Writer. I created a C++/WRL project for that with a function which accepts a stream as a parameter in order for the Sink Writer to write to. The type of this parameter is Windows::Storage::Streams::FileRandomAccessStream. Now it is giving the error saying that the namespace Windows::Storage is not known, and when I include the header file windows.storage.h the error is "use of undefined type 'ABI::Windows::Storage::Streams::FileRandomAccessStream'".

Does anyone know what the problem is and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Ronald

Comment: This sounds very similar to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687502/how-to-return-a-build-in-winrt-component-using-wrl

Answer (score 0):

Runtime classes are a logical concept of the Windows Runtime type system.  When programming at the Windows Runtime ABI layer (e.g. using WRL), you cannot use logical features like runtime classes; only through language projections (like C++/CX) are these features usable.

Instead, programming at the ABI layer is much like COM programming:  there are only interfaces.  You may only refer to a `FileRandomAccessStream` object via one of the interfaces that type implements (e.g. `IRandomAccessStream`).